# Error creating Oracle table invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, identifier

I'm trying to create a table in Oracle 11g, but got ORA-00904 error. The syntax for creating the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Worker(
nif VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) CONSTRAINT PK_Nif PRIMARY KEY,
nameworker VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_NameWorker NOT NULL,
specialty VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_Specialty NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CH_Speciality CHECK (speciality ='ENGINEERING' OR speciality= 'SUPPORT' OR speciality='DEVELOPMENT'),
yearsold INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT CH_Years CHECK (yearsold >= 1),
CONSTRAINT NN_Years NOT NULL,
nifCompany VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_NifCompany NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_NifCompany FOREIGN KEY (nifCompany) REFERENCES Company(nif)
);
```

And the error I got is:

> ```
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

I don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems; the immediate cause of the error is this line:

```
CONSTRAINT NN_Years NOT NULL,
```

which based on the earlier naming you probably meant to include inline with the column definition:

```
yearsold INTEGER CONSTRAINT NN_Years NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CH_Years CHECK (yearsold >= 1),
```

The second problem is that you've got inconsistent names, `specialty` in the column definition vs. `speciality` in the check constraint; so you need to fix the column and not-null constraint names:

```
speciality VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_Specialty NOT NULL,
```

Fixing those things, and assuming you do have a `Company` table with a matching PK for the FK this specifies, gives you:

```
CREATE TABLE Worker(
  nif VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) CONSTRAINT PK_Nif PRIMARY KEY,
  nameworker VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_NameWorker NOT NULL,
  speciality VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_Specialty NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CH_Speciality CHECK (speciality = 'ENGINEERING'
    OR speciality = 'SUPPORT' OR speciality = 'DEVELOPMENT'),
  yearsold INTEGER CONSTRAINT NN_Years NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CH_Years CHECK (yearsold >= 1),
  nifCompany VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) CONSTRAINT NN_NifCompany NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_NifCompany FOREIGN KEY (nifCompany) REFERENCES Company(nif)
);

Table WORKER created.

desc worker

Name       Null?    Type              
---------- -------- ----------------- 
NIF        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)  
NAMEWORKER NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) 
SPECIALITY NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) 
YEARSOLD   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)        
NIFCOMPANY NOT NULL VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are specifying constraint name during column definition. You cannot do that. You should specify constraints differently if you want to give them name.
Try :

```
CREATE TABLE Worker(
nif VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) ,
nameworker VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) ,
specialty VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
CONSTRAINT CH_Speciality CHECK (speciality ='ENGINEERING' OR speciality= 'SUPPORT' OR speciality='DEVELOPMENT'),
yearsold INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT CH_Years CHECK (yearsold >= 1),
CONSTRAINT NN_Years check(yearold is NOT NULL),
nifCompany VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) ,
CONSTRAINT FK_NifCompany FOREIGN KEY (nifCompany) REFERENCES Company(nif),
CONSTRAINT PK_Nif PRIMARY KEY(nif),
CONSTRAINT NN_NameWorker check(nameworker is NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT NN_Specialty check(specialty is NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT NN_NifCompany check(nifCompany is NOT NULL)
);
```

Let me know if you face further issues

Comment: You have `yearold` instead of `yearsold` in `NN_years`, and the `specialty` typo from the original code. Other than that this works, but moving the not-null constraints into out-of-line check constraints means the data dictionary doesn't know the columns are not nullable, in `all_tab_columns` and when describing the table; which looks cosmetic but it can affect the optimizer. You can name not-null constraints in-line to avoid that.

Comment: I can’t really see the point of naming NOT NULL constraints in the first place. It just seems to impose a burden on the schema designer for no benefit. Oracle doesn’t report the custom name on violation anyway, as it uses *ORA-01400 Cannot insert null into (column spec)* for that. (I rather wish there was something similar for foreign keys.)